# Highlighting row and column in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to highlight row and column in a table but not all of them, just until end of selected one td. I'll put a link here to prove what i want, go down and where is size table (size chart) hover on it and you will see:

```
http://www.nike.com/ro/en_gb/c/size-fit-guide/mens-shoe-sizing-chart
```

How can I highlight with limit like that?

Here is my table: https://jsfiddle.net/pkkbf9k2/

Comment: The question us surely interesting, what did you try to accomplish such an interesting goal, though? apart from the fiddle itself (where there is only the "view" part, not the "logic" one)

Comment: i've tried alot on my pc, in fiddle i just insert my table to be easier for someone who want to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's it:
https://jsfiddle.net/8odoros/pkkbf9k2/4/

```
  $( "td" ).hover(
  function() {
    var myCol = $(this).index();
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var myRow = $tr.index()+1;
    $('tr:nth-child('+myRow+') td:lt('+myCol+')').addClass( "hover" );
    myCol++; myRow--;
    $('table tbody td:nth-child('+myCol+')').each(function (index) {
        if(index<myRow)  $(this).addClass( "hover" );
    });
    $(this).addClass('hoverBold');
  }, function() {
    $( '*' ).removeClass( "hover" );
    $(this).removeClass('hoverBold');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar CSS tutorial. It will give you a more better idea.
https://css-tricks.com/simple-css-row-column-highlighting/

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I've already visit this one, but is not what i want, it should stop after hover td not to continue down

Answer (score 0):

Here sample link for highlighting row using jquery
http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-highlight-table-row-record-on-hover-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

You can give the bgcolor to the  tag which you wanted to highlight.
`<td bgcolor="#FF0000">Content</td>`

Or You can give class also to the  tag which you want to highlight.
example
`<td class="highlight">Content</td>`
and give the background color to the style.css file.